# Update TableView (RootView) of SplitView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

In my SplitView application I have some general data in the TableView at startup. When data in the TableView is selected, I want to display detailed data in the TableView at first and when something is selected there, it should be displayed in the DetailView, too. My question concerns the second step: How should I update the data for the TableView and avoid this TableView to disappear when something is selected?

Comment: Maybe if you show the code you're using to make this happen, it would be easier to understand the question.  (For example, a table view doesn't disappear unless the program tells it to, so I'm not sure what's happening there.)

Comment: Looks like you want to use the navigation controller in the split view controller and are looking to see how you can. I provided some code in the answer below. It is long winded, but I am hoping it is useful to you.

Comment: Unfortunately I hadn't the time to check out your suggestions completely, but I'm sure it is the solution I was looking for! Maybe your simple project will help, too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are starting with Apple provided MasterDetail application, what it does by default is the following

1. Creates a split view controller.
2. On the left hand side it has a UINavigationController
3. On the right hand side it has DetailViewController
4. In the AppDelegate it has a UINavigationController with its rootcontroller as MasterViewController. (that is the reason you see MasterViewController) on the left.
5. The MasterViewController on the left does nothing related to navigation controller by default though. Looks like this is where you want to be able to drill down further and get another drill down view and so on.

Steps you need to take

1. First create another DrillDownLevel1ViewController which is a subclass of UITableViewController.
2. In that class, have two properties, one for data and one for reference to DetailViewController.

   ```
   @property(strong,nonatomic)NSArray *drillDownLevel1Data;
   @property(strong,nonatomic)DetailViewController *detailViewController;
   ```
3. In the MasterViewController's didSelectRowAtIndexPath do some thing like this

   ```
    DrillDownLevel1ViewController *drillDownLevel1ViewController = [[DrillDownLevel1ViewController alloc] init];
    drillDownLevel1ViewController.drillDownLevel1Data=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One",@"Two",@"Three", nil];
    drillDownLevel1ViewController.detailViewController=self.detailViewController;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:drillDownLevel1ViewController animated:YES];
   ```
4. In the DrillDownLevel1ViewController, you can correctly set numberOfSections, numberOfRows etc
5. In the cellForRowAtIndexPath of DrillDownLevel1ViewController, set correct value

   ```
       static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
       UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
       if(cell==nil){
           cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
       }


       cell.textLabel.text=[drillDownLevel1Data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

       return cell;
   ```
6. In the didSelectRowAtIndexPath of DrillDownLevel1ViewController

   ```
   self.detailViewController.detailItem = [drillDownLevel1Data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   [self.detailViewController configureView];
   ```
7. DetailViewController on the right hand side should show you the data now. If it is not, then you can do some debugging as to whether the outlets are connected etc.

I have a simple project which I built, if you want I can email it to you.